# Why can I access the internet in a browser but not the terminal?

Tags: ssh, shell, macbook, http, osx-yosemite

I can browse the internet using Chrome and Safari, but when I use the terminal, I can not. When I try to `ssh` in the terminal, I get "request timed out" and when I try to `ping` I get "3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received".
What could be wrong, or what further steps can I take to diagnose the problem?

I am on a wireless connection, with OSX 10.10.

---

Here is the output of `netstat -rn`:

```
[~]$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.12.254     UGSc           50        3     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0       10     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              3    30396     lo0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.12         link#4             UCS             4        0     en0
192.168.12.76      0:b:ab:68:f4:57    UHLWI           0      157     en0    221
192.168.12.99/32   link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.12.103     a0:ed:cd:89:0:d4   UHLWI           0        0     en0
192.168.12.108     4c:7c:5f:ab:40:45  UHLWI           0        0     en0    935
192.168.12.254/32  link#4             UCS             1        0     en0
192.168.12.254     0:6:f6:da:14:c1    UHLWIir        52       24     en0    162
192.168.12.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        2     en0

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::a299:9bff:fe10:7a25%en0           a0:99:9b:10:7a:25               UHLI            lo0
fe80::%awdl0/64                         link#8                          UCI           awdl0
fe80::e896:15ff:fef9:3905%awdl0         ea:96:15:f9:39:5                UHLI            lo0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff01::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%awdl0/32                         link#8                          UmCI          awdl0
```

---

Here is output of `traceroute www.google.com`

```
[~]$ traceroute www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (216.58.216.228), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.12.254 (192.168.12.254)  1.215 ms  12.702 ms  1.475 ms
 2  192.168.247.84 (192.168.247.84)  3.657 ms  4.051 ms  4.202 ms
 3  10.50.249.253 (10.50.249.253)  23.796 ms  27.235 ms *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
```

Comment: There are many possibilities. Do you need to use a proxy? Please include the output of `netstat -rn` in your question.

Comment: @DanielB I've added the output of `netstat -rn`. Looking forward to learning what this means!

Comment: Looks normal. However, you missed the other part of my comment: Do you need to use a proxy to access the Internet?

Comment: @DanielB no ... though I am currently accessing the internet at a public library. I'll try a VPN to see if that changes things

Comment: The public library router is could be blocking ICMP. That is not uncommon. What happens if you try a `traceroute www.google.com`?

Comment: Is the library using a captive portal? Do you have to "sign on" before you get browser internet access?

Comment: @DavidPostill 1) I added the results of `traceroute` (will update when it finishes) and 2) I did not have to sign on to get my browser to access the internet.

Comment: I don't think it will 'finish' given the output so far. Looks like your library network's edge router is blocking ICMP traffic.

Comment: `ssh` is probably blocked as well.

Comment: Their network may only allow 80, 8080 and maybe a couple of other ports. You could use https://www.grc.com/ (or similar) and do a port scan of ports below 1024 and see what is actually open for you to use.

Comment: @DavidPostill Got it. Interestingly, I get the same traceroute output with or without the VPN. However, ssh only works when the VPN is on. Is there any way to use ssh without the VPN?

Comment: Not if `ssh` is blocked ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm checking using OSX Network Utility --> Port Scan. It requests an IP address - presumably I am scanning the remote server for open ports (?). on localhost only 631 is open.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'd invite you to summarize your conclusions as an answer that I can accept. Then I'll proceed using VPN, and then inquire with the librarian.

Comment: No. You need to check from outside the network to your public IP address. grc.com will do that automatically for you. Click on the ShieldsUp image to get started.

Comment: I'll pass. The comments don't really make for a good answer.

Comment: grc.com ShieldsUp says all ports have stealth status, except 445 (microsoft-ds), which is closed. It also says that my connection has no reverse DNS.

Comment: Are you inside a virtual machine when you ssh in the terminal and on the host OS when you open the browser?

Comment: @Back2Basics no I am not in a VM

Answer (score 1):

You may be found the solution by now. This is for future users.

I am using mac mini, and have 2 temporary solutions.

1. I tried restarting mac in safe mode. This checks for any potential problem and resets it automatically. Then again restarting mac normally worked. But faced the same problem again.
2. Then followed these steps -  System Preferences>Network> I turned Wi-Fi off, Went to Advanced>TCP/IP>Configure IPv4 and changed it to off, hit "OK", I went back into >advanced>TCP/IP and turned on Using DHCP, Hit "Renew DHCP Lease" and it finally created a brand new IP address. I haven't faced the problem again but not sure.